# Skipping function keyword throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This example doesn't work:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
    Hello World  </div>
    )
  }
});
```

I compile jsx into js on the client side and the browser throws the error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

This example works:

```
    var App = React.createClass({
      render: function() {    
    return (
      <div>
    Hello World  </div>
    )
   }       })
```

So, how does [react-router](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/) tutorial work without function keyword?

Comment: Works for me -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69z2wepo/7436/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, how does [react-router tutorial](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/) work without function keyword?

This is a relatively new thing, being added as part of ES6 (ECMAScript 6, the next version of "JavaScript.") You can [create methods like that](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-method-definitions), basically, this code in ES6:

```
var obj = {
    foo() {
    }
};
```

is equivalent to this code in ES5 and before:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function foo() {
    }
};
```

(Modulo browser bugs around named function expressions, but no one uses IE8 or Safari 5 anymore, right? Right?)

The new syntax works on recent versions of Firefox and Chrome.

That said, I suspect it's just a minor error in that tutorial, as they only do it in a couple of places and use the older syntax in most places.